# Rearrange array. Make 1, 3, 5 to 3, 5, 1 and etc

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I have an array:

```
int array[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 5, 7}, {4, 2, 1}};
```

How can I randomly make it

```
int array[][] = {{2, 5, 7}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 2, 1}};
```

or

```
int array[][] = {{4, 2, 1}, {2, 5, 7}, {1, 2, 3},};
```

And so on.

Is there any JAVA function to help me? Or I have to figure it out by myself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might convert your array to a `List<int[]>` and call `Collections.shuffle()`. Then convert back to an array.

```
int array[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 5, 7}, {4, 2, 1}};

List<int[]> l = Arrays.asList( array ); //the list returned is backed by the array, and thus the array is shuffled in place
Collections.shuffle( l );
//no need to convert back
```

If you need to keep the original order, you'd have to create a copy of the array (or the list backed by that array), like this:

```
int array[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 5, 7}, {4, 2, 1}};

List<int[]> l = new ArrayList<int[]>( Arrays.asList( array ) );  //creates an independent copy of the list
Collections.shuffle( l );

int newArray[][] = l.toArray( new int[0][0] );
```

Another way:

```
int array[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 5, 7}, {4, 2, 1}};

int newArray[][] = array.clone(); //copy the array direcly
List<int[]> l = Arrays.asList( newArray );
Collections.shuffle( l );
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList` will give you a List backed by the array. So no need to run `l.toArray(..)`...

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple using the `Collections.shuffle(..)` method as the `Arrays.asList(..)` method returns a List backed by the `array`.

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));
```

---

Full example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int array[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 5, 7}, {4, 2, 1}};
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));

    for (int[] a : array)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use collections there is a shuffle method, if you have to use a primitive type such as int, you will have to shuffle it yourself.  Here are examples of both:

http://blog.ryanrampersad.com/2008/10/13/shuffle-an-array-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Try the Collections class that comes with Java. You can use the shuffle() method to randomize the indices to access the arrays.

[Link to Java API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use Collections:
something like this:

```
List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(array);
Collections.shuffle(list);
int[][] shuffledArray = (int[][]) shuffledList.toArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want is random swaps of the contents of the outer array.

You could use java.Random's nextBoolean() to get a true/false as to whether to make a swap, such as between 1&2 or 1&3 or 2&3.

This is assuming you want to work with the primitive types, and not classes.